# Issue with equality between tuple elements and constant values

Tags: python, tuples

```
self.monthAr={"Jan":1,"Feb":2,"Mar":3,"Apr":4,"May":5,"Jun":6,"Jul":7,"Aug":8,"Sept":9,"Oct":10,"Nov":11,"Dec":12}

    def sameDate(self,month,day,datetup):
            print str(month) + " " + str(datetup[0]) + ": " + str(day) + " " + str(datetup[1])
            n= month == int(datetup[0])
            m=day == int(datetup[1])
            print n
            print m
            time.sleep(1)
            if (n and m):
                print "YO WE HERE"
                return True
            else:
                return False    

    def getPast(self, daysPast, apicalls=False):
                dic={}
                a=datetime.date.today()
                #will contain tuples of all dates of interest in form MONTH,DAY,YEAR
                b=[]
                for i in range(0,daysPast+1):
                    d=a- datetime.timedelta(days=i)
                    dateString = str(d.month) +'-' + str(d.day) + "-" +str(d.year)
                    b.append((d.month,d.day,d.year))
                    dic[dateString]= {}
                    dic[dateString]["tweetCount"]=0
                    if(i== daysPast):
                        self.tso.arguments.update({'since': '%s' % d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')})



                try:


                    for tweet in self.ts.search_tweets_iterable(self.tso):
                        date=tweet["created_at"]
                        date=date.split()
                        print date
                        dateMonth= self.monthAr[date[1]]
                        print str(dateMonth) + " datmonth"
                        day=date[2]
                        for x in b:
                            print "got here"
                            #print str(dateMonth) + " " + str(x[0]) + ": " + str(day) + " " + str(x[1])
                            #print self.sameDate(dateMonth,day,x)
                            if(self.sameDate(dateMonth,day,x)):
                                print "got here 1"
                                accessDate=self.tupToString(x)
                                dic[accessDate]["tweetCount"]+=1
                                print "Plus 1 to : %s" % (accessDate,)
                                break

        x=searchTwitter("Bernie Sanders")
        x.getPast(10)
```

Some sample output is here that can be correlated with the code.

```
6 6: 30 30
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 29
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 28
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 27
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 26
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 25
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 24
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 23
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 22
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 21
True
False
got here
6 6: 30 20
True
False
```

My function does not return true in both cases of comparing month and day with the tuple. This is really strange here, for the first output, you can see the months and days are exactly the same, but when comparing the days it says they are not the same. This is really a brain buster for me. If someone could tell me what is causing this issue it would be really appreciated. I feel like it is something simple but its so simple I'm overlooking the problem entirely.

Comment: Can you please edit your code to be exactly what you ran? Including the actual call to sameDate? In your output you're printing "got here", but in the function you're printing "YO WE HERE".

Comment: I edited my post. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: The code you edited in doesn't have the self.sameDay method or the self.monthAr.

Comment: Apologies. I fixed it.

Comment: If nothing is working, you can try to subtract day from dateup[1] and check if it is 0. Instead of day == int(datetup[1]). Just to try another expression. But it should work like atlspin pointed out already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it works fine for me.  I added some parenthesis because I'm running python 3, but other than that it's identical:

```
import time

def sameDate(month,day,datetup):
    print (str(month) + " " + str(datetup[0]) + ": " + str(day) + " " +
        str(datetup[1]))
    n = month == int(datetup[0])
    m = day == int(datetup[1])
    print (n)
    print (m)
    time.sleep(1)
    if (n and m):
        print ("YO WE HERE")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And here is the output for the test case that is failing for you:

```
>>> sameDate(6, 30, (6, 30))
6 6: 30 30
True
True
YO WE HERE
True
>>>
```

So what I'm trying to say is, the problem is not in the code you provided.

Comment: I'm passing a tuple with three elements, that shouldn't change things because I'm just accessing elements right?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

My month and day were in  unicode. Simply convert to int to solve problem.